# Concatenate a string from a file and hard-coded string in Web Service Task Editor

Tags: variables, ssis, flat-file

I have a SSIS solution that has about 45 indivudal packages in it. Each package contains a Web Service Task that is used to pull data from one of our providers that stores data within the cloud.

The issue I am having is that each Web Service Task references a report on the 
providers server by using a "Connection String". This connection string is placed within the "Value" section, on the Input tab of the Web Service Task. BUT our password expires to the provider every 90 days and when the password expires, I have to change the connection string on each package.

The conntection string is structured like so: [encrypted password][report name].

What I would like to do is create a variable that references a .txt. file that has the [encrypted password] portion of the connection string, and concatenate the [report name] portion. So that way, whenever the password changes, it only needs to be changed within the .txt file.

Could someone please give me a hand with creating a variable that concatenates the value within a .txt file and a hard-coded string within the variable writer?

Thank you

Comment: I see no need to save the password in a file. I would recommend to use a parameter and mark it as sensitive. Are you using package or project deployment?

Comment: Project deployment. Can the same parameter you mentioned above be referenced in each individual project? My biggest concern is only have one place to change the encrypted password in one place, instead of 45.

Comment: Do you have several projects?  do you mean packages?

Comment: Yes, sorry. One Project with serveral packages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save the password in a file. If you are using the project deployment model you can simply use a project parameter.

In visual studio under your SSIS project you should see an item named project.params, edit it by double clicking on it.
In the params window add a new parameter and for your password. Say "servicePassword". **Set sensitive to true**.

Go to each webservice task, on the properties tab click on expressions. Select the connection string and set it to: **@[$Project::servicePassword]** + "[reportName]",
where [reportName] is the report for the current webservice task. You may also have to use the webservice url in this step.

After you deploy your project to the SSIS catalog, you can configure your project to use the production password that is valid at the time. Open SSMS, go to integration service catalogs, expand your project folder and then right click your project and select configure. Set the servicePassword parameter.